# Nothing happen delete selected row

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I have deleted selected datagrid, but after debug, then I click delete, but nothing updates. *sorry for my poor English.

This my script:

```
//Delete data buku private void DeleteDataBuku()
{

    String con = (@"Data Source=FAJRI-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dbPerpustakaan;Integrated Security=True");
    for (int i = 0; i < dvgPerpustakaan.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        DataGridViewRow dr = dvgPerpustakaan.Rows[i];
        if (dr.Selected == true)
        {
            dvgPerpustakaan.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
            try
            {
                SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection(con);
                db.Open();
                SqlCommand dbcmd = db.CreateCommand();
                string sql = "delete from Perpustakaan where KodeBuku=" + i;
                dbcmd.CommandText = sql;
                SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
                DataSet myDataset = new DataSet();
                SqlAdapter.Fill(myDataset);
                db.Close();
             }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error");
            }

        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

To make a change in your underlying database you need to execute the command (in your case the Delete command). The whole set of instructions for SqlDataAdapter are of no use in this case.

```
for (int i = dvgPerpustakaan.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0 ; i--)
{
    DataGridViewRow dr = dvgPerpustakaan.Rows[i];
    if (dr.Selected == true)
    {
        dvgPerpustakaan.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
        try
        {
            using(SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection(con))
            using(SqlCommand dbcmd = db.CreateCommand())
            {
                db.Open();
                dbcmd.CommandText = "delete from Perpustakaan where KodeBuku=" + i;
                dbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }

    }
}
```

Also, to avoid problems with the index of your loop you should going backward from the last row to the first because the RemoveAt will change the total number of rows in your grid and you use that value to exit the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when removing the end of a string, I was doing this

```
blahblahblah.remove(6,5):
```

Which removes 5 characters from position 6 and finding nothing was being removed when i reused `blahblahblah`

I fixed this by going:

```
blahblahblah=blahblahblah.remove(6,5):
```

I believe you are having the same issue, you are removing the row from the data grid but not reassigning your data grid back so try:

```
dvgPerpustakaan=dvgPerpustakaan.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
```